# iPhone: How to make a UITextField, UITextView uneditable when switching views

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextfield, uitextview

I have two views - one a table view and other a detail view in my iphone app. When a row in table is selected, the detail view is displayed.

I am using the nib for detail view for editing a record, adding a new record as well as displaying a record. The detail view has a UITextField and a UITextView which need to be made uneditable when I am just displaying the record. In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of tableview I tried this...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    MemoDetailViewController *memoDetailViewController = [[MemoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MemoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    memoDetailViewController.memo = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// making the text field and text view uneditable - DID NOT WORK???
        memoDetailViewController.memoTitleText.enabled = NO;
        memoDetailViewController.memoTextView.editable = NO;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:memoDetailViewController animated:YES];
    [memoDetailViewController release];
}
```

This does not work. The textfield and uitextview remain editable - the keyboard appears when I tap on them. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to go about this is to use their respective delegate methods.  They are the same, only with different names.  Using `UITextField` as an example, you're basic approach would be this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (someCaseWhereYouWantToEdit) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This lets you specify when you want to let it continue to edit.  You of course need to have the textField and textView instances set with `self` as their delegate as well as importing the delegate protocols in your header

Comment: This needs to go in the detail view or the table view? I asked because I need to control the editable behavior from inside the table view - when a row is selected...

Comment: That depends how you have it set up.  If you are using a view controller that holds the tableView, it will just go in the implementation file.  If you're using a tableViewController, it'll go in that implementation file.  That method will be called every time you click on a textField (and similarly textView for its respective method), so you can add any logic you want in there to let it know when to continue to edit (returning YES) or when it should be for display only (returning NO)

Answer (score 4):

You can even disable USER INTERACTION ENABLED in XIB of particular UI Element

Comment: Right, but from memory, doing so will modify the appearance of the components. I'm used to do that because this way the user knows the field is not editable at first glance, but it may not be the desired behaviour. (Example : if you wanna pop a modal view which will fill the field at dismiss instead of popping the keyboard, letting the user believe the field is disabled is not necessarily a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

The code is not working because the view hasn't been loaded from the XIB and hence those properties are `nil` and messaging to `nil` has zero effect. If you alter the order to `pushViewController` first then it should work

```
MemoDetailViewController *memoDetailViewController = [[MemoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MemoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

memoDetailViewController.memo = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:memoDetailViewController animated:YES];

memoDetailViewController.memoTitleText.enabled = NO;
memoDetailViewController.memoTextView.editable = NO;

[memoDetailViewController release];
```

While this works, I would suggest declaring a `BOOL` property. Set it to `YES` or `NO` and later use its value in `viewWillAppear:` method to enable or disable the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the view controller for the view that should be uneditable:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     memoDetailViewController.memoTextView.editable = NO;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    memoDetailViewController.memoTextView.editable = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also use this in both view controller in different-2 time

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
   memoDetailViewController.memoTextView.editable = NO;
 }

 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
   memoDetailViewController.memoTextView.editable = YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{

}
```